# No concurrency (network calls are executed sequentially) using OkHttp

Tags: android, networking, concurrency, okhttp

I am using OkHttp (`com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1`) in a Java Android app.

My assumption was it is possible to have concurrent calls using the `OkHttpClient`. However it does not appear to be the case - the calls are executed sequentially for me.

Here is my setup:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

// for an unclear reason this sill does not allow concurrent calls
dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(32);

OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(
        new HttpLoggingInterceptor(s -> Log.d("KeyValueStorage", s))
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    )
    .eventListenerFactory(new LoggingEventListener.Factory())
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .dispatcher(dispatcher)
    .build();
```

Here are the logs:

```
2021-04-30 18:20:51.945 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [0 ms] callStart: Request{method=HEAD, url=https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/a_0}
2021-04-30 18:20:51.945 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [0 ms] callStart: Request{method=HEAD, url=https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/d_0}
2021-04-30 18:20:51.945 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [0 ms] callStart: Request{method=HEAD, url=https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/c_0}

2021-04-30 18:20:51.954 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: --> HEAD https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/c_0
2021-04-30 18:20:51.955 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: --> END HEAD
2021-04-30 18:20:51.962 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [17 ms] proxySelectStart: https://www.wroclaw.pl/
2021-04-30 18:20:51.966 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [21 ms] proxySelectEnd: [DIRECT]
2021-04-30 18:20:51.966 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [21 ms] dnsStart: www.wroclaw.pl
2021-04-30 18:20:52.056 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [111 ms] dnsEnd: [www.wroclaw.pl/46.248.189.3]
2021-04-30 18:20:52.060 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [114 ms] connectStart: www.wroclaw.pl/46.248.189.3:443 DIRECT
2021-04-30 18:20:52.081 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [136 ms] secureConnectStart
2021-04-30 18:20:52.401 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [456 ms] secureConnectEnd: Handshake{tlsVersion=TLS_1_2 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 peerCertificates=[CN=www.wroclaw.pl, OU=IT, O=Gmina Wroclaw, L=Wrocław, C=PL, SERIALNUMBER=931934839, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=PL, OID.2.5.4.15=Government Entity, CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US, CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US] localCertificates=[]}
2021-04-30 18:20:52.401 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [456 ms] connectEnd: http/1.1
2021-04-30 18:20:52.403 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [458 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{www.wroclaw.pl:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=www.wroclaw.pl/46.248.189.3:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1}
2021-04-30 18:20:52.404 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [459 ms] requestHeadersStart
2021-04-30 18:20:52.405 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [461 ms] requestHeadersEnd
2021-04-30 18:20:53.721 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1775 ms] responseHeadersStart
2021-04-30 18:20:53.722 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1777 ms] responseHeadersEnd: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/c_0}
2021-04-30 18:20:53.725 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1779 ms] responseBodyStart
2021-04-30 18:20:53.725 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1780 ms] responseBodyEnd: byteCount=0
2021-04-30 18:20:53.728 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: <-- 200 OK https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/c_0 (1772ms)
2021-04-30 18:20:53.728 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Server: nginx
2021-04-30 18:20:53.729 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Date: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 16:21:20 GMT
2021-04-30 18:20:53.729 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Content-Type: text/html
2021-04-30 18:20:53.729 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Connection: keep-alive
2021-04-30 18:20:53.729 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Vary: Accept-Encoding
2021-04-30 18:20:53.729 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Set-Cookie: CUMULUS=1; Path=/
2021-04-30 18:20:53.730 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=250CD2E947A8A542D615C8BAB4D45717; Path=/
2021-04-30 18:20:53.730 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Content-Encoding: gzip
2021-04-30 18:20:53.730 11761-11867/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: <-- END HTTP
2021-04-30 18:20:53.731 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1786 ms] connectionReleased
2021-04-30 18:20:53.732 11761-11867/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1787 ms] callEnd

2021-04-30 18:20:53.747 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: --> HEAD https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/a_0
2021-04-30 18:20:53.747 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: --> END HEAD
2021-04-30 18:20:53.761 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1816 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{www.wroclaw.pl:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=www.wroclaw.pl/46.248.189.3:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1}
2021-04-30 18:20:53.763 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1818 ms] requestHeadersStart
2021-04-30 18:20:53.767 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [1822 ms] requestHeadersEnd
2021-04-30 18:20:54.974 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3028 ms] responseHeadersStart
2021-04-30 18:20:54.977 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3032 ms] responseHeadersEnd: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/a_0}
2021-04-30 18:20:54.981 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3035 ms] responseBodyStart
2021-04-30 18:20:54.983 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3037 ms] responseBodyEnd: byteCount=0
2021-04-30 18:20:54.987 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: <-- 200 OK https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/a_0 (1238ms)
2021-04-30 18:20:54.987 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Server: nginx
2021-04-30 18:20:54.987 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Date: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 16:21:22 GMT
2021-04-30 18:20:54.987 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Content-Type: text/html
2021-04-30 18:20:54.987 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Connection: keep-alive
2021-04-30 18:20:54.988 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Vary: Accept-Encoding
2021-04-30 18:20:54.988 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Set-Cookie: CUMULUS=1; Path=/
2021-04-30 18:20:54.988 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0E4D51CDE5F7E91AB5D773973CEBE7A8; Path=/
2021-04-30 18:20:54.988 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Content-Encoding: gzip
2021-04-30 18:20:54.988 11761-11865/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: <-- END HTTP
2021-04-30 18:20:54.991 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3045 ms] connectionReleased
2021-04-30 18:20:54.992 11761-11865/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3047 ms] callEnd

2021-04-30 18:20:55.002 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: --> HEAD https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/d_0
2021-04-30 18:20:55.002 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: --> END HEAD
2021-04-30 18:20:55.011 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3066 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{www.wroclaw.pl:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=www.wroclaw.pl/46.248.189.3:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1}
2021-04-30 18:20:55.013 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3067 ms] requestHeadersStart
2021-04-30 18:20:55.017 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [3071 ms] requestHeadersEnd
2021-04-30 18:20:56.203 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [4257 ms] responseHeadersStart
2021-04-30 18:20:56.207 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [4260 ms] responseHeadersEnd: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/d_0}
2021-04-30 18:20:56.211 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [4265 ms] responseBodyStart
2021-04-30 18:20:56.212 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [4266 ms] responseBodyEnd: byteCount=0
2021-04-30 18:20:56.218 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: <-- 200 OK https://www.wroclaw.pl/get/me/d_0 (1214ms)
2021-04-30 18:20:56.218 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Server: nginx
2021-04-30 18:20:56.218 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Date: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 16:21:23 GMT
2021-04-30 18:20:56.218 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Content-Type: text/html
2021-04-30 18:20:56.219 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Connection: keep-alive
2021-04-30 18:20:56.219 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Vary: Accept-Encoding
2021-04-30 18:20:56.219 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Set-Cookie: CUMULUS=1; Path=/
2021-04-30 18:20:56.219 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=399BA09A7BD030FE7CA775873C7C7C78; Path=/
2021-04-30 18:20:56.220 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: Content-Encoding: gzip
2021-04-30 18:20:56.220 11761-11868/com.my.app D/KeyValueStorage: <-- END HTTP
2021-04-30 18:20:56.224 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [4276 ms] connectionReleased
2021-04-30 18:20:56.227 11761-11868/com.my.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [4279 ms] callEnd
```

The logs show how I have 3 network calls (each from its own thread) using the same single instance of the `OkHttpClient`. To my surprise they do not interleave at all.

Ideas I tried (without success):

- Note, the HTTP protocol is HTTP/1.1. So I also tried with a server that uses HTTP2.
- Tried different Android devices.
- Tried both Wi-Fi and Cellular networks.
- Tried with a custom `OkHttp` `Dispatcher` of a fixed 16-threads pool executor.

Comment: You haven't actually shown how you are making requests. It should be concurrent if you either make multiple synchronous calls (execute) with different calling threads, or make multiple async calls (enqueue) so you don't wait for call completion.  It's not obvious from the example code what is restricting it to a single request at a time.

Comment: @YuriSchimke I tried both approaches. However the networking itself is sequential regardless.

Comment: Sure, but can you actually provide a reproducible code example? From the example you just show how you create an OkHttp instance and then the logs.

Comment: @YuriSchimke, I will provide my sample code a bit later. Meanwhile I found there was a seemingly related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58385954/247013

Comment: That example seems to leak responses, so maybe the prune method is triggering?

Comment: @YuriSchimke I investigated the matter a bit deeper and it seems that what I was looking for is HTTP1.1 pipelining or HTTP/2 multiplexing. HTTP1.1 pipelining is not supported by OkHttp (and for good). HTTP/2 multiplexing is probably simply invisible at the debug level I am using. Or since I do such a small bodiless HEAD requests - I should not expect any benefits from multiplexing. P.S. I do close responses, if that is a concern.

Comment: It should open multiple connections for HTTP/1.1 to ensure some concurrency.